Wrapping Sol results into Error: IncorrectProgramId
I have a PD vault account, I transfer some amount of SOL to WSOL token account for this vault and then I try to call the SyncNative instruction that results into err:
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
  'Program log: Instruction: SyncNative',
  'Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 884 of 153908 compute units',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction',
  'Program 7Ppq5s4BFH4uyx3p8y4e33Sp7GL9NCBJeBcrw8ojnY6z consumed 46976 of 200000 compute units',
  'Program 7Ppq5s4BFH4uyx3p8y4e33Sp7GL9NCBJeBcrw8ojnY6z failed: incorrect program id for instruction'

here is a piece of code:
    // Sync the native token to reflect the new SOL balance as wSOL
    let cpi_accounts = token::SyncNative {
        account: wsol_account.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = token_program_account.to_account_info();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, vault_signer);
    token::sync_native(cpi_ctx)?;

and here are the accounts I pass the call:
 { pubkey: vault, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
 { pubkey: signer, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
 { pubkey: SYSTEM_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
 { pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
 { pubkey: vaultAssociatedTokenAccount, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }


I finally figured out the problem:

I was not initializing the ATA(I assumed it happens automatically when doing a transaction), the owner of the ATA was not the Token Program

One more point worth noting is this bug: GitHub Issue, quoting billythedummy:
I think this means programs cannot do the following basic procedure: transfer lamports to a wSOL token account by directly decrementing lamports from a program owned account SyncNative the wSOL account


